# How to implement SSG in Vite+Svelte

Tags: svelte, vite, static-site-generation

I'm implementing a Vite + Svelte template, and I correctly completed the project.
When I run:

```
npm run build
```

the script builds a `/dist` folder in which I have scripts, chunks, assets and index.html. In this index.html entry-point file there's an "app" root element and DOM will be injected later by Svelte.
This works fine, but I would like to avoid client-side rendering, and instead pre-render the entire HTML structure with SSG in order to improve SEO.

Is this possible using the standard Vite (+ Svelte) installation/template?

Answer (score 0):

SvelteKit was created to use Svelte as a SSG (as well as SSR). It also runs in a Vite environment. You do need to use the [Static adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters#supported-environments-static-sites) to build it as a static site.

I recently put my [first SvelteKit App](https://github.com/ngblaylock/scoresheet) (SSG) up on Github that you can reference. In my app, the build files are found in [/docs](https://github.com/ngblaylock/scoresheet/tree/master/docs) where you can see each page was generated as a `.html` file.

If you don't want to use SvelteKit you can check out [Astro.js](https://astro.build/). I haven't personally used it but you can use Svelte with it. Otherwise I don't know of any way to build Svelte as a static site.